# Rotation of a known matrix into another known matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, rotation, sympy, rotational-matrices

I have a 6x3  Matrix M_start which provides coordinates in xyz.
I also have an end Matrix 6x3 M_end, which provides the coordinates of the desired matrix.
I now need to know which rotations around x y and z have to be applied to get from M_start to M_end.
The Equation is [RzRyRx][M_start]=[M_end]

For this, I tried to use the 3x3 RotationMatrix RzRyRx, which Wikipedia provides and used it on M_start to get a set of 18 Equations. Since i have only 3 variables only 3 equations are needed. These Equations i tried to solve with SymPy's solve() and nonlinsolve().
Sadly, the solution takes forever in the case of solve, and nonlinsolve provides an output which i dont really understand.

"ConditionSet((a, b, c), Eq((2.02015*sin(c) - 0.708642*cos(c))*cos(b) + 0.6677*sin(b) - 1.0154, 0) & Eq(-0.1967*((sin(c) - 1.122*cos(c))*sin(b) - 0.6853*cos(b))*sin(a) - 0.1967*(1.122*sin(c) + cos(c))*cos(a) - 0.0285, 0) & Eq(0.2201*sin(a)*sin(c) + 0.1967*sin(a)*cos(c) - 0.1967*sin(b)*sin(c)*cos(a) + 0.2207*sin(b)*cos(a)*cos(c) + 0.1348*cos(a)*cos(b) - 0.323, 0), ProductSet(Complexes, Complexes, Complexes"

Here is my code:

```py
from sympy import symbols, cos, sin, Eq, solve, nonlinsolve

a, b, c = symbols('a b c')
# Gleichungen für die Werte
eq1 = Eq(0.2201*sin(a)*sin(c) + 0.1967*sin(a)*cos(c) - 0.1967*sin(b)*sin(c)*cos(a) + 0.2207*sin(b)*cos(a)*cos(c) + 0.1348*cos(a)*cos(b), 0.323)
eq2 = Eq(-0.1967*(cos(a)*(cos(c) + 1.122*sin(c)) + sin(a)*(-0.6853*cos(b) + sin(b)*(-1.122*cos(c) + sin(c)))), 0.0285)
eq3 = Eq(0.6677*sin(b) + cos(b)*(-0.708642*cos(c) + 2.02015*sin(c)), 1.0154)


solution = nonlinsolve((eq1,eq2,eq3), (a, b, c))

print(solution)
```

Do you have any other ideas how to solve for the angles a b c or what I am making wrong with this method?

Comment: I'm not sure the reasoning is quite right here: it is not sure that a, b, and c exist (consider M_start = 2 * M_end, then no such rotation matrix exists) nor are unique (imagine M_start = M_end = 0, then any a, b, c satisfies your equation). Do you have more assumptions on M_start and M_end?
Moreover, matrix sizes in your equation don't really work (in particular, R x M_start is not possible).

Comment: The rotation matrix exists, since a program i am using already did the rotation, but slightly wrong ( i have to rotate it on 90° more), and now i have to do it by hand not using the programs algorithm. 
I confused the matrix sizes, it should be 3x6, you are right. 
M_start and M_end are not 0 and also not equal. 
In detail, here are the matrices:

Comment: # Matrix start
matrix1 = np.transpose(np.array(
                    [[0.134819278, -0.196742231, 0.220766771],
                    [-0.874283722, -0.544579231, 1.553994771],
                    [-0.587264722, 0.982924769, -1.159154229],
                    [-0.667699722, 2.020153769, -0.708642229],
                    [-1.598599722, 0.497746769, -1.396776229],
                    [0.117048278, 0.938185769, -2.045812229]]))

Comment: ```python
M_end = np.transpose(np.array(
                  [[0.323738425, 0.028548749, 0.000334069],
                  [1.15558905, -1.46302634, 0.002484488],
                  [-1.62881025, -0.040371652, 0.002605095],
                  [-1.95174685, -0.434232317, 1.01545285],
                  [-1.85352078, -0.75189964, -0.86796569],
                  [-2.0051881, 1.00801092, -0.205852296]]))
```

Comment: There are 4 different real solutions for the angles (mod 2pi). Do you want to find any one solution or all four of them? If you just want any solution then use a numerical solver rather than using `nonlinsolve`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic solution to your problem.

First, let's rename your matrices `m1` and `m2`. You can see each of these matrices as a could of 3D points. You want to find a rotation `R` which maximises correlation between these two sets (in your specific case, you assume this correlation can be perfect because you know `m1` is a rotation of `m2`).
This problem is called the Procustes problem, and can be solved using the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm).

You can simply compute the desired matrix using a solver for this problem in `scipy`:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy

m1 = np.array(
    [
        [0.134819278, -0.196742231, 0.220766771],
        [-0.874283722, -0.544579231, 1.553994771],
        [-0.587264722, 0.982924769, -1.159154229],
        [-0.667699722, 2.020153769, -0.708642229],
        [-1.598599722, 0.497746769, -1.396776229],
        [0.117048278, 0.938185769, -2.045812229],
    ]
)

m2 = np.array(
    [
        [0.323738425, 0.028548749, 0.000334069],
        [1.15558905, -1.46302634, 0.002484488],
        [-1.62881025, -0.040371652, 0.002605095],
        [-1.95174685, -0.434232317, 1.01545285],
        [-1.85352078, -0.75189964, -0.86796569],
        [-2.0051881, 1.00801092, -0.205852296],
    ]
)

# Compute rotation
r, _ = scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors(m1.T, m2.T)

# Check results
print(r.as_matrix())
assert np.allclose(m1 @ r.as_matrix(), m2)
```

For more details on how this works, you can read [this subsection of a blog post on the Procrustes problem](https://simonensemble.github.io/posts/2018-10-27-orthogonal-procrustes/#the-analytical-solution). It explains that you can solve the Procrustes problem by using the Singular Value Decomposition of the correlation matrix of `m1` and `m2` and gives an analytical proof for that.